# How to make a listbox, whose items can be edited at runtime, in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I want to know, how to make a listbox, whose items can be edited dynamically, at runtime. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) with one column and specify [IsReadonly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.isreadonly(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false` to indicate editing is allowed. Style it as necessary.

Comment: Nice idea! Creative!

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you!